# PAM module bash script on sudo breaks Zenity - /bin/bash failed: exit code 126 - /bin/bash failed: exit code 126

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, pam

I've been messing around with **PAM** module on **Kubuntu 18.04** (basically Ubuntu 18.04) and can't seem to figure out why suddenly I have permission issues running my bash script whenever user does `sudo` command.

Here is my `/usr/local/bin/test.sh` file code:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/zenity --info --text="It Works!"
```

And here is my `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file code:

```
#%PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0

# My PAM test runs here
auth       required   pam_exec.so /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/test.sh

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

Whenever I try `sudo -i` it returns me this error message:

```
bin/bash failed: exit code 126
```

asks for password and when correct password is entered, prints another error line:

```
bin/bash failed: exit code 126
```

I double checked that `/usr/bin/test.sh` has all necessary permissions.

My question is - **what am I doing wrong here? How can I correctly call this and trigger *zenity* message box as a test?**

### Update 1

Here are some fixes i've tried without a success:

- `/usr/bin/test.sh` permissions are: `-rwx--x--x 1 root root`
- both `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash` work
- prepending `"DISPLAY=:0"` didn't help

### Update 2

Allright one step closer to fixing it, but still having issues:

I added `stdout` after `auth required` and it fixed the issue if I use `echo` for example, but if I run `/usr/bin/zenity --info --text="It Works!"` it prompts out a new error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused  (zenity:5046):
Gtk-WARNING **: 05:52:37.200: cannot open display:  /bin/bash failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: The exit code lets think that `bash` can't find something. I guess you should use the shebang `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` in `test.sh`. The fact that the sh short in `/bin/sh` doesn't link anymore to bash or a functional shell in `sudo` context could explain your sudden trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Zilog80 I'll check it out in an hour, you actually may be right. Because I got it working before - same logic, different content of bash script.

Comment: Allright, so it didn't work. Good thinking though.

Comment: Add a line "DISPLAY=:0" after the first line in test.sh might make it work.

Comment: I've tried this before @Roadowl also doesn't work.

Comment: We can guess then that the exit code comes from `zenity`. In `test.sh`, use `/usr/bin/zenity --info --text="It Works!" >>/tmp/pam_zenity.log 2>&1` to get a feedback of the potential zenity trouble .

Comment: Allright I added `stdout` after `auth required` and it fixed the issue if I for example `echo`, but if I run `/usr/bin/zenity --info --text="It Works!"` it promts out a new error:
`Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(zenity:5046): Gtk-WARNING **: 05:52:37.200: cannot open display: 
/bin/bash failed: exit code 1`

Comment: Setting DISPLAY on its own only works if you don't need additional authentication tokens, such as XAuthority, to access the X server.

Comment: The `Gtk-WARNING **: 05:52:37.200: cannot open display:  ` say us that there is no `DISPLAY` defined at the time.  As you have pam session `user_readenv=0`, i guess you rely on a X settings script somewhere ?

Comment: @Zilog80 yeah, basically no display way assigned. I added `--display=:0.0` for Zenity and it worked.

Comment: I have follow up question, maybe you have idea. If i'd like to promt this zenity message box on login screen, i understand that simply moving that line from `/etc/pam.d/sudo` to /etc/pam.d/login` won't work, but I would like to know how would you prompt let's say message box on login screen that asks for PIN? @Zilog80

Comment: Run `xhost +` from a terminal running on your desktop

Comment: If you want to do that through PAM, it's possible in your shell script with `$PAM_RUSER` which give you the user login name which requires authentication while `$$PAM_USER` will give you the target authentication login. With `$PAM_RUSER` you can look for the corresponding X settings (via `Xauth` or a $HOME settings file). As your script will be called at each PAM session (login and logout), you should check `"${PAM_TYPE}" = "open_session"` if your script is for a PIN check.

Comment: @Zilog80 first of all thank you for your time & effort. I tried your suggestion all together with `expose_authtok` and everything worked like a charm when I am logged in, using `sudo -i` or saving files as `sudo`. However once I log or lock out, I can't log back in. I'm going to post another question about this, as this is another topic and gets deeper with each new addition and harder to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

No display defined for Zenity to prompt the message in.

### Solution

Add display for whatever visual scripting you're doing within bash - in my case it was appending `--display=:0.0` for zenity like so:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/zenity --info --text="It Works!" --display=:0.0
```